# Is it possible to get the index of a exchange using Finance::Quote?

Tags: perl, finance, stocks

I need to get the index of a exchange like NASDAQ rather than the price of a specific stock in that exchange. I suppose that [Finance::Quote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Finance::Quote) will come  to the rescue , but after a quick go-through of the document, I find it the way one can use the module for query is like:

```
   %info = $q->fetch("australia","CML")
```

which means both the exchange and the stock should be specified in the query. then the question is: does the index itself can be treated as a stock and has a symbol name which can be used in the query?

Of course, if you have other way can meet my needs rather than using Finance::Quote, please feel free to write down your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the symbol for the nasdaq composite is "^IXIC". For nyse composite it's "^NYA".

each quote provider might have a different syntax though.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your question is that you are assuming that there is just one index for a particular exchange. Whilst there may well be a particular index that is dominant (eg. for stocks primarily traded on the London Stock Exchange, the FTSE 100 might be considered the main index; similarly for the NYSE it would be the Dow Jones Industrial Average) other exchanges may have a less clear leader in their collection of associated indicies (eg. for the Australian Stock Exchange, the S&P/ASX 200 and the All Ordinaries index are both frequently quoted side-by-side in the evening broadcast news).

Symbology of stocks, indicies, option chains, futures, etc is quite a complicated field in financial IT. Many of the symbology standards are backed by a data vendor (eg. Reuters, Bloomberg) and use of their standards requires a commercial license. On the other hand there are other efforts aiming to make symbology more open (Bloomberg themselves are behind [one of these efforts](http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/)).

I'm not familiar with the data sources of the Finance::Quote package you reference, but if you are serious about accessing market data (ie. prepared to pay for it) but don't need the cost/complexity/speed of a solution from Reuters, Bloomberg, etc, you could do alot worse than check out what [Xignite](http://www.xignite.com/) offers in the way of market data accessible via web services.

Comment: 'one of these efforts' link broken